# ethereum wallet running a private net 0 peers 0 waiting for blocks

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, cpp-ethereum

am using geth

```
VRSION:
   1.8.20-stable-24d727b6
```

and ethereum wallet `Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-9-3` and i am using Ubuntu `18.04.1 LTS` in the geth console i started the miner but either is not incrementing it stays at 0 and also on the wallet it shows 0 peers and 0 waiting for blocks  i stared to start and stop the minor several times with 
`miner.start(1);` and `miner.stop()` 
on the geth console it only says

```
INFO [12-14|18:34:31.542] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1000000000
INFO [12-14|18:34:31.543] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash=9091da…9b902a uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=468.863µs
```

here is my genesis file

```
{
"config":{
        "chainId": 45,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 12
    },
"nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
"timestamp": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"extraData": "0x",
"gasLimit": "0x8000000",
"difficulty": "0x200",
"config": {},
"mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333", "alloc": {}
}
```

the expected behavior is there should be either in  my main account continuously incrementing and numbers of blocks as well

Comment: What is the command line you use to launch geth? Did you create an account? Check the output from geth perhaps an error causes mining to not start.